# Logging eviction in EhCache using CacheEventListener

Tags: logging, ehcache, event-listener

I am trying to use `EhCache` in my project with Tomcat 6. The EhCache I am using is version 1.4 as it is already being used in my project with Hibernate. I have written my own custom CacheEventListener (included below) and it works except for one problem with `notifyElementExpired()`. It seems like `notifyElementExpired()` is only called when I add something else to the cache. On a side note, `notifyElementPut()` is getting called all right.

Can someone suggest a solution to this?

```
public class EhCacheEventListener implements CacheEventListener {
  private Logger log4j =
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());   

  public void notifyElementRemoved(Ehcache cache, Element element) throws CacheException {
    log4j.debug("cache element removed---->"+element.getKey());
  }

  public void notifyElementPut(Ehcache cache, Element element) throws CacheException {
    log4j.debug("cache element put---->"+element.getKey());
  }

  public void notifyElementUpdated(Ehcache cache, Element element) throws CacheException {
    log4j.debug("cache element updated---->"+element.getKey());
  }

  @Override
  public void notifyElementExpired(Ehcache cache, Element element) {
    //log4j.debug("Element creation time is "+element.getCreationTime());
    log4j.debug("cache element expired---->"+element.getKey());
    //log4j.debug("Element expiry time is "+element.getExpirationTime());
  }

  @Override
  public void notifyElementEvicted(Ehcache cache, Element element) {
    log4j.debug("cache element evicted---->"+element.getKey());
  }

  public void notifyRemoveAll(Ehcache cache) {}

  public void dispose() {}

  public Object clone(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Elements are checked for expiry in `ehcache` at the following times:

When a `get` request is made
When an element is spooled to the diskStore in accordance with a `MemoryStore eviction policy`. 
In the `DiskStore` when the expiry thread runs, which by default is

```
Cache.DEFAULT_EXPIRY_THREAD_INTERVAL_SECONDS
```

For More details check out : [ehCache Documentation](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/event/CacheEventListener.html#notifyElementExpired%28net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache,%20net.sf.ehcache.Element%29)